# siunitx: Problems with xparse after update on 2016-03-31

Tags: texlive, siunitx, expl3, xparse

Dear community members,

after today's (2016-03-31) update of packages via `TexLive Utility` severe problems with `siunitx` showed up on Mac OS 10.10.5 + TexShop.

`siunitx` calls `xparse`, which then outputs the following `LaTeX Warning:`

```
You have requested, on input line 53, version
           `2016/03/28' of package expl3,
           but only version
           `2016/03/26 v6466 L3 programming layer (loader) '
           is available.
```

and thereafter the `Package xparse Error:`

```
Support package l3kernel too old
```

If you switch off `\usepackage{siunitx}` in the following MWE everything works well.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
A formula: $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.
\end{document}
```

How to handle that issue?
Thanks in advance for your support. Frank

Comment: Search the site. You are not the first today with this problem.

Comment: Just use the `restore backup package` feature of `tlmgr` to revert

Comment: How to do that with the TexLive Utility?

Comment: click on `backups`,  enter `l3` in the search field, then click on `restore` for the 4 corresponding "packages".

Comment: apart from that the tip by @UlrikeFischer elsewhere about modifying line `\def\ExplFileDate{2016/03/26}%` of file `expl3.sty` to `\def\ExplFileDate{2016/03/28}%` seemingly worked for me, but this is better not attempted if you are not familiar with how packages are laid out in TeXLive (for example on my installation I have no need for sudo, but this will be needed in `99%` of cases).